# Foreach two DatePeriod Object

Tags: php, date, foreach

I want to create scheduling for my web. How can I get schedule with 2 days per weeks. Example: show Monday and Friday every week. This is my code:

```
$day_of_week = "Monday";
$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';
$start = new DateTime("");
$end   = clone $start;
$start->modify($day_of_week); // Move to first occurrence
$end->add(new DateInterval('P7W')); // Move to 1 year from start
$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="lihatAbsen.php?tanggal='.$date->format('d-m-Y').'&id='.$id_kuliah.'">'.$date->format('d M Y').'</td>';
}

$day_of_week2 = "Friday";
$start->modify($day_of_week2); // Move to first occurence
$period2  = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period2 as $date) {
    echo '<td><a href="lihatAbsen.php?tanggal='.$date->format('d-m-Y').'&id='.$id_kuliah.'">'.$date->format('d M Y').'</td></tr>';
}
```

Its working but i want to get the `$period2` object printed in the same row `<tr></tr>` with `$period` object. How to do the right loop? Or how to get 2 days/weeks with input days?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Oh, and +1 for using clone and DateInterval and DatePeriod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone your current `$date` object and move it to the next Friday.

```
$day_of_week = "Monday";
$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';
$start = new DateTime("");
$end   = clone $start;
$start->modify($day_of_week); 
$end->add(new DateInterval('P7W')); 
$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="lihatAbsen.php?tanggal='.$date->format('d-m-Y').'&id='.$id_kuliah.'">'.$date->format('d M Y').'</td>';

    $friday = clone $date;
    $friday->modify('next Friday');
    echo '<td><a href="lihatAbsen.php?tanggal='.$friday->format('d-m-Y').'&id='.$id_kuliah.'">'.$friday->format('d M Y').'</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the first date in it's loop and add it to the output text string

```
$monday=$date->format('d-m-Y');
$friday= date("d-m-Y",strtotime("$monday +4 days"));
```

Comment: Mixing DateTime() with date() and strtotime? yuck.

Comment: Nice constructive criticism. Guys like you make this site such a treat.